# Comparison between xamarin and ionic in cross platform mobile development

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, xamarin, ionic-framework, windows-mobile

I have to admit I know very little about mobile development but after some research it seems that xamarin and ionic are two popular frameworks for cross platform mobile development using .net. Though I don't a great deal of either of them l.

I wonder what are the main differences between using Xamarin for front to back and using ionic with .net web api as backend? Of course xamarin is not free whereas ionic is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Xamarin**

- Write apps in C#
- Create complete native UIs
- Covers frontend and backend programming
- Not free

**ionic**

- Write apps with Javascript + HTML + CSS
- Create good looking UIs which are **not native**
- Basically used for creating UIs. Use other JS frameworks for backend programming.
- Free to use

Comment: So would you say using xamarin is better in terms of productivity as it covers the full stack?

Comment: Xamarin is IMHO the better choice as it provides the better tooling with VS2015 integration and great NuGet packages as well as the opportunity to create fully native applications. But that's only my opinion. Take the comparison and decide on your own what's important for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just looked into Xamarin pricing a bit further and they offer free student licence and discount to small companies and start-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft bought Xamarin and made it free removing that concern for adoption.